# how find list of all available WiFi printers in android

Tags: java, android, wifi, printers, android-print-framework

I am developing application where I want to find all available WiFi enabled printers and print file on it.

To find available list of devices currently I am using WifiP2pManager but its not working as expected.

Note: Google Cloud Printing is not a desired solution

Answer (score 3):

If the API level you are using is greater than 19. You would need the use of the [android.print](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/package-summary.html) class.

You would also need an adapter derived from [PrintDocumentAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintDocumentAdapter.html). This adapter provides the content of a document to be printed.

As for getting the connection to the printer without Google Cloud Printing is a tough one. However, there are [SDK](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/)s and a similar [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19985/how-can-i-send-a-file-wirelessly-without-bluetooth-or-a-wi-fi-network-in-ics) about that subject.

Or you could also try and set up a P2P connection with the printer, learn that [here](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html)!